# No se conecta a la base de datos en Hoostinger

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Antes de comentar deseo que decir que al momento de subir a un Hosting se cambian la información necesaria de acuerdo al hosting para conectar a la base de datos.

Cuando ejecuto el programa en PHP de manera local funciona  perfectamente accede a la base de datos, puedo eliminar, editar sin ningún problema; pero cuando subo el programa a un Hosting no funciona no se conecta no se observan los datos disponibles en la base de datos.

Agregue lo siguiente:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Y me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'xxxxxxxxxx' doesn't exist in /home/xxxxx000/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/xxx.php:217 Stack trace:
> #0 /home/xxxxx000/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/xxx.php(217): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT * FROM u...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/xxxxx000/domains/xxxx.com/public_html/xxx.php on line 217

Ya tengo 3 semanas tratando de encontrar el problema consultando en la red y no logro encontrar el problema por esa razón he decidido preguntar en este foro recomendado por mi proveedor de alojamiento de páginas web ya que aquí se me comentan que es una comunidad de programadores profesionales que se ayudan para ayudarse a solucionar problemas en sus proyectos por esa razón busco ayuda de los expertos.

¿Podría alguien decirme? porque de manera local si funciona el programa conectándose a la base de datos y poder eliminar o editar; pero al subir al Hosting no funciona. Agradezco su ayuda.

Envío el código para su análisis y esperando algún comentario que me ayude a resolver este problema. Gracias.

Código

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
       
        //Conectar a la base de datos mysqli
        $conexion= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db) or die ( "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
        $resultado="";
      global $nombre, $correo, $telefono, $mensaje, $consultar, $buscar, $row,$busqueda;
  
      if( isset($_REQUEST['enviar'])) {
    $busqueda=$_REQUEST['busqueda'];
  
    if( isset($_POST['busqueda']))
    {
          $resultado="SELECT * FROM $db WHERE id LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR correo LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR telefono LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR mensaje LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
    }   }else {
    echo('<center>************************************ <center>');  }
     $conexion= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);  $SQL="SELECT * FROM $db WHERE id LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR correo LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR telefono LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR mensaje LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
    $buscar=mysqli_query($conexion, $SQL) or die("No se conecta");
    if($buscar -> num_rows > 0)
    { // while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar))
                      {
      
      ?> <tr> <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?> </td> <td><?php echo $row['correo'];?> </td> <td><?php echo $row['telefono'];?> </td> <td><?php echo  $row['mensaje'];?> </td> <td> <button type="button" style="font-size:20px; background:yellow"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o editbtn" >Editar</i> </button>  <button type="button" style="font-size:20px; background:red" name="eliminardato"><i class="fa fa-trash-o deletebtn" >Eliminar</i> </button>
```

Comment: Hola Mario. El error que comentas es debido a que no se encuentra una tabla en la base de datos, hiciste la migracion de tu base de datos correctamente? revisa como realizas esa acción y si estan todas las tablas del proyecto

Comment: Gracias Julio he revisado paso a paso incluso he agregado unas líneas para que me muestre un mensaje de  tabla seleccionada y conectado con el servidor y efectivamente me muestra tabla seleccionada y conectado al servidor; pero sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje y lo extraño es que de manera Local funciona perfectamente y al momento de ejecutarlo en el servidor no funciona en el servidor tengo varias tablas; pero en el programa busco la manera de decirle a cual tabla debe dirigirse, ¿No sé si tengas un código para especificar que seleccione una tabla de varias? Aclaro no soy Experto.